# Why is suggested-edit not allowed on non-tag wiki post on SE meta sites?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, per-site-meta

I recently saw a disabled `edit` link on question on a meta, hovering over which showed this message.

[image: non-tag wiki post]

I would like to know, why are suggested edits on non-tag wiki post on other Stack-exchange meta sites not allowed? Any particular reason ?